# Symfony lifetime CSRF token

Tags: php, symfony, security, csrf

How can I get a lifetime (expires) of CSRF token in Symfony 3? I want to set the meta tag "refresh" on my login page in order to avoid errors with csrf token expired.

Comment: `A CSRF token is not an access token and does not have a lifetime like bearer tokens do. They are generated using session information.` So why you want to put lifetime of CSRF token ?

Comment: @Bhavin lifetime of session is same that lifetime of csrf token? I need the information about lifetime of csrf token because I have an error when my session is expired and I'm trying to login again. I want to set <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH"> with time of csrf token expire.

Comment: I think you have some misunderstanding regarding CSRF Token. Please read this question and answer it'll clear all the questions regarding CSRF Token. :- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22903/why-refresh-csrf-token-per-form-request

Comment: @Bhavin thank you for the article, I've read it. I think I understand what is CSRF token now. But how can I fix an error about expired token on the login page (after session expired)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following is a better solution than `changing the CSRF token lifetime`.

However, the point behind CSRF tokens is that they change frequently so that nobody can try to steal one of those tokens and then use it to make a forged request. Here's the workflow I always used in my application. So, PHP Frameworks Doesn't matter logic remains the same I have done this process in Laravel, CodeIgniter, Symfony etc.

- Request a CSRF token.
- Use the token to make requests.
- If the request fails because the token has expired, go to step 1.